# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'grailsResourceProcessor' on null object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, grails-2.0

I get the following error when working with Grails 2.3.6 and resources:1.2.1. Is there a workaround for this error:

```
Resource reload failed!:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'grailsResourceProcessor' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure20.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:204)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure20.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:191)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor250.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.call(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.call(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_triggerReload_closure7.run(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Don't have a `null` object.

Comment: I do not have a null object!

Comment: Exception stack trace says otherwise: `Cannot get property 'grailsResourceProcessor' on null object`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis grailsResourceProcessor is not part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-248 it sounds like the issue is caused by forked execution.

Try turning off forked execution, and seeing if you have the same errors. That should hopefully get you far enough along while the resources plugin is fixed.

Also, are you using the latest version of the resources plugin?

Comment: I use resources:1.2.1

Comment: In that case, I'd try it without forked execution.

If you're not a fan of that, and don't want to wait until the new version comes out, you could also try switching to asset-pipeline for resource / asset management. https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin